# HRESULT E_FAIL Error -2147467259 when using IEnumDataset.Next()

Tags: raster, arcobjects, c#

I'm writing a Desktop Add-In that scans our directories and pulls in georeferenced raster images that contain a point geometry. While it's been working on many image file types so far for some reason I get the HRESULT E_FAIL error when I get to these files via IEnumDataset.Next():

[image]

```
private static void PullImages(IPoint centerpoint, string directoryPath)
{
    IWorkspace ws; IDataset dataset; IRasterDataset rasterDataset; IRasterLayer rasterLayer;
    ws = RWSF.OpenFromFile(directoryPath, 0);
    IEnumDataset enumDataset = ws.get_Datasets(esriDatasetType.esriDTRasterDataset);
    dataset = enumDataset.Next();

    while (dataset != null)
    {
        rasterDataset = (ws as IRasterWorkspace).OpenRasterDataset(dataset.BrowseName);
        IEnvelope rasterEnvelope = (rasterDataset as IGeoDataset).Extent;
        rasterEnvelope.Project(NAD83);
        if ((rasterEnvelope as IRelationalOperator).Contains(centerpoint))
            {
                rasterLayer = new RasterLayerClass();
                rasterLayer.CreateFromDataset(rasterDataset);
                RemoveHistogramStretchAndMinimize(ref rasterLayer);
                MXD.AddLayer(rasterLayer);
            }
        dataset = enumDataset.Next();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it with just the sid file only?

Comment: I tried moving just the sid file to a test folder and passing its path to the method, but I got the same HRESULT E_FAIL error. I'm also not able to pull the sid into ArcMap with either the extra files or on its own.

Comment: I don't think you need to call `OpenRasterDataset`. Have you tried casting  `dataset` to `rasterDataset` instead?  Also how are you creating `RWSF`?  I've always wondered what sort of errors occur when you don't follow Esri's advice to use `Activator.CreateInstance` to create the workspacefactory.

Comment: If you cannot even load the sid file into ArcMap would suggest the sid file is corrupt in some way and your code is OK?

Comment: @Hornbydd I think you are correct, I should have tested that beforehand. I still get other errors on files that I can pull in but I will start another thread.

Comment: @KirkKuykendall, yes casting dataset to IRasterDataset works as well. For the RWSF I have a static singleton object at the top of my class, I will look into using Activator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files shown in the screenshot above were corrupt.